# ArrayList = Finding Composite or Prime Numbers

Tags: java

I am working on an "ArrayListFunHouse" program which mainly involves factors.

There are two methods: a method for finding the factors of each number besides the number itself and one, as well as another method for finding which factors are composite and/or prime, and removing all prime numbers from the array.

Here is the main program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class ArrayListFunHouse
{
   public static ArrayList<Integer> getListOfFactors(int number)
   {
      int i=0;
        ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      for(i=2;i<=number-1;i++){
         if(number%i==0)
            factors.add(i);
      }
      Collections.sort(factors);
      return factors;
   }
   public static void keepOnlyCompositeNumbers( List<Integer> nums)
   {
       /*

       //GET HELP FOR THIS PART

       */   

   }
}
```

note that I left the finding composite numbers method empty, because I honestly have no idea what to do there. Trying other solutions from the internet don't work.

Here is the runner:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class ArrayListFunHouseRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        System.out.println(ArrayListFunHouse.getListOfFactors(9));

        System.out.println(ArrayListFunHouse.getListOfFactors(23));

        System.out.println(ArrayListFunHouse.getListOfFactors(50));

        System.out.println(ArrayListFunHouse.getListOfFactors(100));

        System.out.println(ArrayListFunHouse.getListOfFactors(762));    

        Integer[] nums = {2,6,8,9,10,12,13,15,17,24,55,66,78,77,79};
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList(nums) );

        System.out.println( list );
        ArrayListFunHouse.keepOnlyCompositeNumbers( list );
        System.out.println( list );
    }
}
```

This part of the runner:

```
Integer[] nums = {2,6,8,9,10,12,13,15,17,24,55,66,78,77,79};
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList(nums) );

System.out.println( list );
ArrayListFunHouse.keepOnlyCompositeNumbers( list );
System.out.println( list );
```

relies on the composite number method, which is supposed to remove prime numbers from the array, as I have already said.

I have already figured out everything related to the first method. It is just the second method I am stuck on.

Comment: The idea for `keepOnlyCompositeNumbers` is that you can loop through the list, for each number n, you call `getListOfFactors`. Then if the return list is empty => n is prime. so you can remove n out of the list.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making your method a predicate rather than altering the list that is passed in. That way you can use it in many different ways (with examples below).

So:

```
public static boolean isComposite(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can easily remove composites from your list with:

```
list.removeIf(ArrayListFunHouse::isComposite);
```

Note that `removeIf` was added in Java 8 but there's easy ways to achieve the same effect in previous versions.

A slightly more elegant way if you are familiar with Java 8 streams might be to return a stream from your factor finder then use that in the composite checker:

```
public static IntStream getFactors(int number) {
    return IntStream.range(2, number).filter(n -> number % n == 0);
}

public static boolean isComposite(int number) {
    return getFactors(number).findAny().isPresent();
}
```

Then finding composite factors becomes:

```
List<Integer> compositeFactors = getFactors(number)
    .filter(ArrayListFunHouse::isComposite)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There's really no reason to sort the collection as it is already sorted as it is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this for the method keepOnlyCompositeNumbers.




public static ArrayList<Integer> keepOnlyCompositeNumbers( List<Integer> nums)
       {
           List<Integer> compositeList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
           for(Integer num:nums){
               int count=0;
               for(int i=2;i<num;i++){
                   if(num%i==0){
                       count++;
                   }

                   }

               if(count!=0){
                   compositeList.add(num);

               }
               }
           return (ArrayList<Integer>) compositeList;
           }

}
```

Try this to print those composite numbers.

```
        System.out.println( list );
        List<Integer> compositeList1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        compositeList1= ArrayListFunHouse.keepOnlyCompositeNumbers( list );
        System.out.println( compositeList1 );
```